# How to undo dist-upgrade?

Tags: bios

I was trying to find a way to resize correctly my window for virtual box(to get it full screen) , however at one point I executed the command get-apt dist-upgrade and I think this command break my computer running on Ubuntu 16.04

The computer boots but I can't use my keyboard(can't open a terminal) or my mouse on my desktop. So I taught about rebooting in secure mode but I don't know how to do it. My computer is a dell so I did F12 to enter Bios and then I hold esc so I enter the grub. Instead of having an option to boot in secure mode I just have a command line. I used the command "reboot" and now I'm in the Bios.

How can I do to boot in secure mode?
I have a save of many of my files in a USB drive, how to get back to that save or undo that apt-get dist-upgrade?

Thanks. !

Comment: An `apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't do anything but applies upgrades with fewer restrictions than upgrade; it won't do anything wrong to your system unless you have polluted your sources that allow packages from other release, distributions or other unofficial sources than your xenial/16.04 release. Restoration from that will depend on your backup strategy, or file-system choices (some allow for rollbacks, standard installations do not activate any of this so you would have had to plan ahead before-hand).  I'd suggest booting a 'live' system & backup first if you don't have good backups.

Comment: The other thing I'd do is edit grub and have it boot to runlevel 1 (removing `quiet splash` too so all messages are shown) and explore sources for potential issues, look through the apt log to see what actually occurred, though that's all detail likely easier from a GUI provided by a 'live' system in prior comment.  Note when using the 'live' system, the / file system will refer to the live system created in memory; so your actual system on disk will be where it was mounted.

Comment: Okay thank you, i will try to do what you said

Comment: Sorry my advice was hurried & hardly friendly/easy.  The ' 1 ' is a 'linux' kernel option that is added to force the system to stop at runlevel 1 (ie. maintenance mode), the 'quiet splash' are also kernel options that are removed so more messages show (provides clues, though likely not helpful to non-technical users).   This may help them to be applied (you don't want to save them, it's temporary impacting the current boot only, ie. use 'e' to edit, make change & press <F10> to boot. A 'live' system allows GUI & regular GUI options so I'd suggest that if unfamiliar with terminal/commands.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: It's ok no worries. I checked online to see what was the runlevel 1. 
I tried to live boot but it didn't work, so i'm trying with another version (first was 16.04.1 and now 16.04.6 - i only know that i'm running on 16.04 but the last  nuber i don't remember).

Comment: For editing grub i just have a command line i don't have the different options like "Advanced options for ubuntu" "Memory test".